# How many ways to sum up to 2017 by adding 1 , 2 and 4

Tags: combinatorics

Given numbers 1, 2 and 4, how many ways there are to add up to 2017, with order not mattering?

I searched but can't find a systematic solution to this. This is supposed to a middle school level math problem.

Comment: @Arthur _"order doesn't matter"_

Comment: Do it for a smaller number first, say $10$, instead of $2017$. It may be too small for general patterns and formulas are apparent, but it should give you a place to figure out things like how you could even begin to count all the ways without, for instance, missing some of them, or counting some of them several times because you forgot that you had included them in your count.

Comment: This is the coefficient of $x^{2017}$ of $$\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^4}=\frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2)}{(1-x^4)^3}$$

Comment: It's 2018, time to update your contest problem questions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative integers such that $$a+2b+4c= 2017$$

We see that $c\leq 504$ and for each fixed $c$ you have that $b$ is at most $1008-2c$, since $$ 2b\leq a+2b = 2017-4c$$

So for each $c$ we have  $1008-2c+1$ possibilites for $b$. For each $b$ (and $c$) we have determined uniqly $a$. So we have

$$(1009-2\cdot 0)+ (1009-2\cdot 1)+...+(1009-2\cdot 504)=505 \cdot 1009
-2{504\cdot 505\over 2}=505^2$$
solutions.

Comment: Hmm I have got different then orlp

Comment: My answer now matches yours, Thomas found the error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is the intended middle school solution.

---

First note that we're always going to use at least one $1$, because $2017$ is odd and the other two numbers are even. So we can instead ask the number of ways to sum up to $2016$, knowing that we'll also tack one $1$ at the end.

Let's start with the solution of all $4$s, since $2016$ is divisible by $4$. $2016/4 = 504$, so we need $504$ of them to do it.

Now for each $4$ we have the option of splitting it into two $2$s. And for each $2$ we have the option of splitting it into two $1$s.

Let $k$ be the number of $4$s we split into $2$s and $l$ be the number of $2$s we then split into $1$s. Then our total amount of possibilities is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{504}\sum_{l=0}^{2k} 1 = \sum_{k=0}^{504}(2k+1) = (505)^2 = 255025$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned it's enough to find the answer for 2016 (instead of 2017) and just add a single 1 onto each number.

So let's count according to the number of 4s.

There is 1 way to write 2016 as all 4's, namely $4 \times 504$.

There are 3 ways to write 2016 with 503 4s, namely $4 \times 503 + 2 \times 2, 4 \times 503 + 2 \times 1 + 1 \times 2, 4 \times 503 + 1 \times 4$.

There are 5 ways to write 2016 with 502 4s, namely $4 \times 502 + 2 \times 4, 4 \times 502 + 2 \times 3 + 1 \times 2, 4 \times 502 + 2 \times 2 + 1 \times 4, 4 \times 502 + 2 \times 1 + 1 \times 6, 4 \times 502 + 1 \times 8$.

This pattern can be extended; there are $2k + 1$ ways to write $2016$ with $504 - k$ 4s, for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, 504$.

So the total number of ways to write $2016$ is $1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + 1009$, the sum of the first $505$ odd integers.  This is $505^2$ by the well-known identity

$$ 1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + (2n-1) = n^2$$

As a sanity check, we could say that the number of ways to write $4n + 1$ as a sum of 1, 2, and 4, with order not mattering, is $(n+1)^2$.  For $n = 1$ this says that there are $(1+1)^2 = 4$ ways to write 5: these are

$$ 4 + 1, 2 + 2 + 1, 2 + 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.  $$

And similarly there are $(2+1)^2 = 9$ ways to write 9: these are

$$ 4 + 4 + 1, 4 + 2 + 2 + 1, 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1, 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1, 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1, 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1, 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1, 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1. $$

Answer (score 0):

Since $2017$ is odd, you have to have a least one $1$.  After that, you can specify any number of $2$s and $4$s that sum to $2016$ or less, filling out the remainder with $1$s.  The number of ways to do this is equal to the number of ways to specify a number of $1$s and $2$ that sum to $1008$ or less.  By letting the number of $2$s range from $0$ to $504$, this number is

$$1009+1007+1005+\cdots+5+3+1=505^2$$

(The final result uses the well known fact that the sum of the first $n$ odd integers is $n^2$. This may or may not, of course, be well known at the middle school level.)